# Sound fluctuations in Windows 10 laptop

Tags: audio, acer-aspire, digital-audio, audio-output

I am using Windows 10 laptop.I am facing some audio problems..My problem is the sound level-It changes depending on the charging condition..If my laptop is plugged in The sound level is very low..while It is UNPLUGGED..THE SOUND LEVEL is decently loud..
I have reinstalled The OS.. Reinstalled the Sound Driver..and other possible things....But without result..

But I have noticed one thing...
My laptop has Realtek HD Audio Driver installed..and it causes the above mentioned problem..
But when my laptop didn't have that driver installed..(the Default Microsoft Audio Driver was installed)it didn't cause that sound level fluctuations problem..BUT THE SOUND WAS NEARLY INAUDIBLE..
That's why I had to install that Realtek Driver..which gave me fairly loud sound..BUT GIVING ME THAT SOUND FLUCTUATIONS PROBLEM..DEPENDING ON CHARGING CONDITION..
ANY help plz??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not a Hardware problem..Rather a Hard Reset did the trick..After Clean Installing the Windows..